# How @Transaction works in interceped method

Tags: java, transactions

In my service I have method:

```
@Transactional
public void doSomething(String dbName) {

}
```

this method is intercepted by my interceptor:

```
@Override
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    // do something
    return invocation.proceed();
}
```

My question is what is in transaction. Just code which in in my service or also in my interceptor ?

Answer (score 0):

That really depends. Using `@Transactional` opens a transaction only if you defined spring to use transactions by `<tx:annotation-driven/>` (if you use XMLs for configuration) and if the interceptor uses the bean created by spring.

In case you don't use the spring bean, the `@Transactional` annotation has no meaning and won't do anything because spring creates a wrapper/proxy of the original class in which it manages the transactions.

You can look at the instance of the class that runs `doSomething()` and see whether it contains only your private fields, or it also has additional transaction data. Also look at the type of the class - if it's transactional it will show a name indicating that's a wrapper and not your original class name.

The transaction itself runs only around `doSomething()`. This means that when you enter `doSomething()` a transaction opens, and it ends when `doSomething()` finishes.

That's unless the `invoke()` call is also under a transaction. In case `invoke()` is under a transaction, the `doSomething() will run at the same transaction and won't open a new one (meaning they both fail or success together).

Comment: If the `invoke` participates depends on the ordering of the aspects. If it is executed before the `TransactionInterceptor` then it isn't transactional, else it is and will participate in the same transaction.